# How to convert a string to a class name

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: instantiate class from name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096700/c-instantiate-class-from-name)

For example, if I have

```
string s = "myObject";
```

So how can I use that String s to make this one?

```
return new myObject();
```

I tried this one but it's quite silly and it's wrong

```
return new s();
```

Thank you

Comment: What you're trying to do is hard in C++, at least for the general case.  You might think about using a language that better supports this sort of operation.

Comment: same question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096700/c-instantiate-class-from-name

Comment: because i'm trying to use factory pattern, i know this problem can be solved by Java, but i'm learning c++ so i want to give it a try

Comment: @user552279 - That's your answer; Use the factory or registry pattern. You can find tons of examples with google.

Comment: The factory pattern is just **one class responsible for creating/instatiating** your objects. So when you need to change it you will change only one class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a simple factory and register the classes you want to be able to construct. This is a very light-weight sort-of reflection.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <class T> void* constructor() { return (void*)new T(); }

struct factory
{
   typedef void*(*constructor_t)();
   typedef std::map<std::string, constructor_t> map_type;
   map_type m_classes;

   template <class T>
   void register_class(std::string const& n)
   { m_classes.insert(std::make_pair(n, &constructor<T>)); }

   void* construct(std::string const& n)
   {
      map_type::iterator i = m_classes.find(n);
      if (i == m_classes.end()) return 0; // or throw or whatever you want
      return i->second();
   }
};

factory g_factory;

#define REGISTER_CLASS(n) g_factory.register_class<n>(#n)

int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   REGISTER_CLASS(string);

   std::string* s = (std::string*)g_factory.construct("string");

   printf("s = '%s'\n", s->c_str());
   *s = "foobar";
   printf("s = '%s'\n", s->c_str());

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called [virtual constructor (pattern)](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENDE412&q=virtual%20constructor%20pattern&aq=4&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=virtual%20constructor). The availability of this feature in a language is not necessarily coupled to the language being interpreted or managed by a VM - it depends on how (and if at all) the information about types existing in a program (or library) is available at run time. This is not the case in "naked" C++ - but it can be implemented, as shown by Arvid, for example. The problem is that there is no standardized implementation of this feature, so everybody keeps re-inventing this again and again. To certain extent COM or it's platform independent counterpart XPCOM "standardize" this at component level.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in c++, by design. In c++, there is a clear distinction between a type and an object, which are two very different entities of the language. You can thus only instantiate a type and get back an object, and decide to do so at compile time (c++ does not provide any kind of reflection system unlike c# or java).

However, you can use a factory / registry for the objects you want to instantiate that way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29) to do that. But C++ AFAIK doesn't support reflection.

Interestingly [QT C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29#Qt.2FC.2B.2B) Supports some kinda reflection. Look at the [C# section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29#C.23) for how its done there, and Javascript has one function to do this. Its called [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to do this with C++ since the code run on it's own. Only interpreted languages, such as PHP, or programs that are run through interpreters allows this kind of feature.

Comment: Objective-C, which is a compiled language, supports this behaviour quite easily.

Comment: Java is compiled, and does this quite readily.

Comment: There are work around to achieve the same in C++. The way the PO wants it, Objective-C and Java supports this because there is a VM running those.

Comment: there is no VM running Objective-C.  And I don't see how that matters for the Java case, either.

Comment: Objective-C does *not* run in a VM. And the fact that Java is running in a VM has nothing to do with the fact that it's a reflective language. Last time I looked, Lisp is compiled as well.