# C++ Pointer type cast from class name

Tags: c++, pointers

How to cast a Pointer in C++ from class name in String?

Psuedocode:

```
int * ptr = something;
myStruct ptrstruct = (ClassFromString("myStruct") ptr); 
// The class/struct name is passed in as String
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear; what do you want this code to do?

Comment: I don't think C++ supports this kind of reflection directly.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the "Class Factory" design pattern.  This can be implemented in C++ fairly easily, but is not a language feature.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the problem you want to solve if you had such a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a c++ guru but I have two ideas that may help with brainstorming:

- May the use of the registry pattern as described here would be of help: [Instantiate class from name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096700/instantiate-class-from-name)
- Secondly, following the registry pattern idea you could crate a function for casting e.g. `MyClass something = registry.cast("MyClass", ptr);`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but this must work
Only Void pointer or boost can help, if it happens

```
thing * p = something; // pointer to object
void * pv = p;          // pointer to void
thing * p2 = static_cast<thing *>(pv); // pointer to the same object
```

Maybe same kind of situation is while returning values from Threads
Overall reflection is not possible in c++.
Its just brainstroming.

Comment: That looks almost entirely unrelated to what the OP is asking.

Comment: I see you what you did here, however I don't think you understood the question - partially due to my bad wording. But as an example: Something like this `thing * p2 = static_cast<"thing *">(pv);` Do you see what I did there? That is the effect I am trying to get.