# how to create a class from an identifier?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

the title might be a bit misleading, but I want to give some instance of a class an instance of a different class through polymorphism. I think that may have been even more misleading so I'll give an example;

Say I have a class called `Spell`, that is a parent class to the class `Firebolt`. I want another class, say `Character`, to be able to have the spell, 'Firebolt', in an its memory without ever having to #include the files for 'Firebolt'.

Now, I can think of a way that prior games have done this before. By giving each spell (or whatever else specific class type) a static const string ID or name and in spell having some function that can access this ID/name and `return` a `new Firebolt()` if they are the same.

This sounds pretty good actually, the problem I'm having is I don't know how to code this. I'm not sure how I can access these ID's from the parent class, and I'm not sure how to make a virtual function that will actually return the correct `Spell`. Any help would be amazing. I'll also provide the actual class code I'm working with here in case it might help you guys to answer, or someone with a similar problem to solve it.

The parent class;

```
class Art {
    std::string name;
    int EPCost;
    int castTime;
    int AoESize;

public:
    Art(std::string n, int cp, int ct, int as):name(n), EPCost(cp), castTime(ct), AoESize(as) {}

    virtual ~Art() {}

    static Art* findArt(std::string ID);

    int getAoESize() {return AoESize;}

    std::string getName() {return name;}
    int getEPCost() {return EPCost;}

    virtual int getBaseDamage() = 0;
};
```

The subclass;

```
class FireBolt:public Art {
    static const std::string name;
    static const int EPCost;
    static const int castTime;
    static const int AoESize;
    static const std::string ID;

public:
    FireBolt():Art(name, EPCost, castTime, AoESize) {}

    ~FireBolt() {}

    int getBaseDamage();
};
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use polymorphism for this?

Comment: Perhaps not thinking about returning the correct `Spell` would help. What about just making it perform an `action()` (via polymorphism) and not worry about which subclass it is that performs it?

Comment: @john I dont think I ever said that I didnt want to use polymorphism? Im not 100% sure I know what you mean Ted

Comment: `FireBolt` implements something common to all `Spell`s - I chose to call that `action()`. Whenever the owner of said `Spell` wants to use it, just call its `action()`.

Comment: I think we're both a bit confused. It seems your actual question is how to create a class from an ID, that's strictly independent of the issue of polymorphism (although a polymorphic hierarchy is one place you might want to do that).

Comment: @john Sorry if the title is wrong or the wording misleading. What would be a better way to word this so that someone else with the same problem can find this?

Comment: I don't know, how to create a class from an identifier, sounds OK to me. BTW I'm positive this question has been asked before on SO, so you might do a little searching.

Comment: @CoolDudde For instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096700/instantiate-class-from-name

Comment: @CoolDudde The straight way is to use a [_Decorator Pattern _](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) for your `Character`class. Though that won't work well with collecting specific enhancements over time for a specific  `Character` instance,

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make your `FireBolt::ID` public.

```
class FireBolt:public Art {
public:
    static const std::string ID;
    ...
};

Art* Art::findArt(const std::string& ID)
{
    if (ID == FireBolt::ID)
        return new FireBolt(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I dont think this will work because Art does not have access to FireBolt's ID like that.  Firebolt is a subclass of Art, so Art does not inherit Firebolts ID variable.

Comment: @CoolDudde It will work because `FireBolt::ID` is both public and static. Try it.

Comment: OK, so the issue for you is not wanting to `#include "FireBolt.h"`. In that case just make the IDs global constants and put their declarations in the header file along with `Art`.